# How to quantize ppq time to position in audio buffer

Tags: audio

i'm currently working on the sound sequencer. I decided to use PPQN as time grid. And now i have this problem:
Let's say that tempo is 120 BPM, PPQ is 96 (default values) and sample rate is 44100 Hz. That makes 1 pulse equal to 5.2 ms which is 229.32 Samples (5.2ms*44.1samples/ms). So the position in buffer will be [229.32]. And now i can truncate this 0.32 samples so that every third pulse will be one sample larger than other or interpolate it somehow.

Any ideas or maybe somebody knows the proper way?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the Processing language? If not, you should remove the processing tag and add the tag for whatever language you are actually using.

Comment: didn't realize that, it should be "audio processing"